# .htaccess redirects rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking for the way to employ a redirect rule for all links that have following structure:

```
 http://page.com/common/roar/results.htm?something_goes_there
```

I've tried with the following rules but neither works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.)common(.)$ http://page.com [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} common [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} common
RewriteRule ^ http://page.com/? [L,R=301]
```

I could do all the redirects by hand but I want to ensure that no new redirects will be required.

Thank you.

Comment: Where do you want to redirect to?

Comment: It's still unclear what you want to redirect, all URIs which start with common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically the following rule should work (maybe you're missing `RewriteEngine On`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^common http://page.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've checked my htaccess - the RewriteEngine is on. However the rule you are proposing MrTux is still not redirecting.
I still get 404

Comment: Your idea MrTux eventually worked out. The issue was that I was including it at the end of my .htaccess file, after manual redirects (Redirect 301 / kinda fashion). When I've placed your rewrite rule just next to RewriteEngine declaration it started to work. Thank you for your help MrTux.